# Properties of sphere

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $C$ be a circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$. Then it is well known that for any $P$ on the circle $C$
the angle $\angle APB =\frac \pi 2$. There are similar results for sphere?

Answer (score 1):

You might be asking:

> Does a cone with apex on a hemisphere and encompassing the circular base have a solid angle independent of the position of the apex?

in which case the good folk over at MathOverflow have [done the work for you](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201281/thales-semicircle-theorem-in-higher-dimensions) and proved that the answer is **No**.

If you are asking about *any* similar result, though, they [have an open question on that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201370/is-there-any-counterpart-to-thales-semicircle-theorem-in-higher-dimensions?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a plane passing through $A,B,P$ as any three points are coplanar. You are left with a circle on this plane. You can now conclude.

Comment: It is not the answer I expected. For any three points A, B, C in a sphere. Choose P in the sphere, consider AP, BP, CP and moving P in the sphere, there is some invariant quantity?

Comment: @Chung.J Edit your post to add that. Currently, it seems you are asking this only.

Comment: What is  included  in "similar"? Another dissimilar example is, if you project a right angled triangle on sphere from North Pole onto a plane at South Pole you get a bigger similar triangle.(Stereo-graphic projection).